# Adding parameters to Flare.json For Treemap

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, flare

So currently I am working with http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/, and making the treemaps custimizable. They work fine, however if i add a parameter to every level, the nodes end up being layered over each other. is there any limitation to amount to parameters being passed in flare.json?

For example`{
name: "Sitemap",
type: "main",
children: [
{
name: "International Relations",
type : "notmain",
children: [
{`...

Here i am adding the type column

Comment: There is no limitation about the parameters. In your example, you forgot to add the semicolon "," after the type.

Comment: That was a typing mistake. But i am still facing this issue. Would it be possible to link to an example where this would be working?

Or rather what is a flare.json format? In all examples they show only name and value/size?

Comment: You can write a jsfiddle, that way it will be easier to help you.